# Javascript - Pulling img src from a different location and using the img src in another location

Tags: javascript, html

Still pretty new to JavaScript, but I am trying to go into one site and parse the img src and then go back to my site and use that img src. The reason being is that the img produced on a site is always changing everyday. Whenever I point to that img src, after the day passes the img will break.

I am able to parse the img src from site1 but when I want to implement this at site2 I am unsure how to approach this.

```
<script>
 var someimage = document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_rvwp');
 var myimg = someimage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
 var mysrc = myimg.src;
 alert(myimg.src);
</script>
```

I am not sure how to do this if I were to implement this code in a different site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will run into cross-domain issues trying to do this with JavaScript. If the owner of the other domain is OK with it, they can make some edits that allow you to pull from their site.

[See here](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/)

[Another option with jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)

Do you have other options on the server side such as PHP?

Comment: I guess I should've mentioned that I am doing this within SharePoint 2010. Would that change things?

Comment: In theory, no. But since you have Sharepoint you do have an IIS server which potentially allows you to do this with server side code. It's a bit complicated, but my approach would be to set up another site on the IIS server, then use .NET to get and parse the contents of the page. Your JS would call the new site which would have to be set up to allow cross-domain (see above links)